# 83 23 [Error] 'count' was not declared in this scope (this is the error i am getting in this code and the error is written in the code with the line)

Tags: c

I am getting error in this code i in count what to do?i have idea of count and its functionality and its work it is working in the function  .but  the error is still in **insert function** can anyone pl explain this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>   struct node {
        int data;
        struct node *next; }*head;

        void append(int num) {
        struct node *temp,*right;
        temp= (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=num;
        right=(struct node *)head;
        while(right->next != NULL)
        right=right->next;
        right->next =temp;
        right=temp;
        right->next=NULL; }
```

add function

```
 void add( int num ) {
        struct node *temp;
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=num;
        if (head== NULL)
        {
        head=temp;
        head->next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
        } } void addafter(int num, int loc) {
        int i;
        struct node *temp,*left,*right;
        right=head;
        for(i=1;i<loc;i++)
        {
        left=right;
        right=right->next;
        }
        temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=num;
        left->next=temp;
        left=temp;
        left->next=right;
        return; }
```

This is the function in which i am getting the error can anyone pl explain this?

```
void insert(int num) {
        int c=0;
        struct node *temp;
        temp=head;
        if(temp==NULL)
        {
        add(num);
        }
        else
    {
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if(temp->data<num)
        c++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    if(c==0)
        add(num);

   else if(c < count()) \\ 83   23  [Error] 'count' was not declared in this \\scope

        addafter(num,++c);
    else
        append(num);
    } }
```

Delete function

```
 int delete(int num) {
    struct node *temp, *prev;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    if(temp->data==num)
    {
        if(temp==head)
        {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
        }
        else
        {
        prev->next=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prev=temp;
        temp= temp->next;
    }
    }
    return 0; }
    void  display(struct node *r) {
    r=head;
    if(r==NULL)
    {
    return;
    }
    while(r!=NULL)
    {
    printf("%d ",r->data);
    r=r->next;
    }
    printf("\n"); }
    int count() {
    struct node *n;
    int c=0;
    n=head;
    while(n!=NULL)
    {
    n=n->next;
    c++;
    }
    return c; }
    int  main() {
    int i,num;
    struct node *n;
        head=NULL;
        while(1)
        {
        printf("\nList Operations\n");
        printf("===============\n");
        printf("1.Insert\n");
        printf("2.Display\n");
        printf("3.Size\n");
        printf("4.Delete\n");
        printf("5.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");
        if(scanf("%d",&i)<=0){
            printf("Enter only an Integer\n");
            exit(0);
        } else {
            switch(i)
            {
            case 1:      printf("Enter the number to insert : ");
                     scanf("%d",&num);
                     insert(num);
                     break;
            case 2:     if(head==NULL)
                    {
                    printf("List is Empty\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    printf("Element(s) in the list are : ");
                    }
                    display(n);
                    break;
            case 3:     printf("Size of the list is %d\n",count());
                    break;
            case 4:     if(head==NULL)
                    printf("List is Empty\n");
                    else{
                    printf("Enter the number to delete : ");
                    scanf("%d",&num);
                    if(delete(num))
                        printf("%d deleted successfully\n",num);
                    else
                        printf("%d not found in the list\n",num);
                    }
                    break;
            case 5:     return 0;
            default:    printf("Invalid option\n");
            }
        }
        }
        return 0; }
```

Comment: You invoke `count()` in code that has no clue as to its existence. And fyi, `n` passed to `display(n);` down in `main` is wrong, as it is declared, but never set to anything, thus its value is indeterminate and its use invokes *undefined behavior.*

Comment: Stop posting non-answers as answers. You can edit your question for any updates. Your code needs at least a function prototype (google that) for `count()` so calling code knows what it looks like if it hasn't already been told by prior-definition (which is also possible by moving the definition *above* any functions with referencing code in the source file).

Comment: for this i have posted the code with the count pl scroll down

Comment: this error resolved new error    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'delete'

Comment: Completely different issue.

Comment: yes i know but it came after this error in the same code

Comment: yes .. finally compiled actually delete was  a reserved word so i used del and it worded pl mark this as solved

Answer (score 0):

Hey I couldn't see any count function in you code write that first and compile. If count is a variable then using it as a function would be wrong.

I think you need to know more syntax because The comment like style you used to show line which you think as error is not correct in C. In C we use two style either `/* ... */` or `// ...`

Comment: It's a function in the code block where `main` is, obviously considerably after its first-use in `insert`.

Comment: see the second cone which i posted so it has count function

Comment: Write a prototype of count at top (before it's use) and try

Comment: how to do that pl tell me.

Comment: it's simple. just add a line at top of your code:        int count();

Comment: [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'delete'

Comment: I have edited your second code please look below the code there is a button named edit press it it will take you to a page where from a textbox you can copy the code and try compiling it. I compiled the code and it works fine

Comment: its still not working    [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'delete'

Comment: yes .. finally compiled actually delete was  a reserved word so i used del and it worded pl mark this as solved

Comment: delete is not a keyword in C but in C++